# Which of these video dimensions is correct for a video shot on an iPhone?

Tags: ffmpeg

Which of these 2 dimensions are correct, if I want to re-encode this video to mp4 format?

I shot a video using an Apple iPhone, and then using FFmpeg, I checked for its dimensions etc.

It shows dimensions as 480x360:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov

Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709)
, 480x360, 707 kb/s, 25.12 fps, 25 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
            handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
```

Now, I ran the following FFmpeg command on the video, to pull out a frame from it:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vframes 1 out.png
```

The image is in 360x480 pixel format.

Which of these dimensions should I use in the following command?

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:10 -i input.mov -vf scale={w}:{h} part1.mp4

ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:10 -i input.mov -vf scale={w}:{h} part2.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your video has displaymatrix side data with rotation info. So `ffmpeg` will automatically rotate this video -90 degrees. If you don't want it to auto rotate then add the `-noautorotate` input option before `-i`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but which dimension size should I use in the last 2 commands I posted above? Should I use the pixel size taken from the frame "out.png" (360x480), or should I use the one given by metadata 480x360 size? Thanks. Also, I do not want to use noRotate flag.

Comment: @JohnSmith 360x480 is the portrait resolution of 480x360 landscape resolution. The video dimensions depend on whether your video is in portrait or landscape. If you are looking at providing for other iPhones, be aware that they can have [different screen dimensions](https://28b.co.uk/ios-device-dimensions-reference-table/)

Comment: @ChrisRogers You don't have to use the scale filter or declare `w` or `h` unless you want to re-size the video. The input is 480x360, and if you use `-noautorotate` then the output will be 480x360. If you do not you use `-noautorotate` for this input, then the output will be 360x480.